# Iphone - Safari - detect swipe navigation

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, swipe-gesture

I'm having a bit of a problem with mobile safari's swipe animation:

I've created a popup window of sorts, for the search functionality (with a similar purpose and look to ebay's mobile site. Go to ebay on mobile, and focus on the search field and it will overlay a sort of popup over the entire site)

The difference, however, is that I've added a pushstate command so that when you open the search popup, it advances the browser history. That way, if a user wants hits "back" on the browser, it'll just close the popup instead of going to whatever previous page the user came from.

Another thing is that I've created an animation for the window's appearance and disappearance. So when you focus on the search field, the popup appears by sliding from right to left, and also goes away in a similar fashion.

Here's the problem, though: iPhone's swiping navigation functionality destroys the sliding effect -
when you open the popup, it advances you forward in the browser's history. Now, if you try to go back by using the swiping functionality, it shows the sliding animation of the previous page into view (iPhone's default), but then, as it's done, my code kicks in (because ultimately, it triggers the popstate event) and also does the sliding animation, so it looks broken. So, as a result, the way it looks is: you swipe to go back to the previous page which shows the search popup being pushed out of the view (just like my animation), and then when you're done, boom, the animation reappears, and plays again.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to detect the swipe functionality somehow. That is, some event, or something in the popstate event to indicate that a swipe navigation is, or has just occurred?

Or perhaps, being able to disable safari's default effect? (to which the answer, I suspect, is a big fat NO)

Is there anything I could do about any of that stuff short of disabling my custom animation when I detect safari, or doing away with the pushstate functionality?

Any advice towards a solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution?